# Cant build ios app using flutter on a mac because of google mlkit

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I build the app for android using flutter build apk and everything works just fine.

The problem appears when i try to run flutter build ios. It does not build because i depend on google mlkit for text recognition and barcode recognition.[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPXuC.png)

Please help

Build ios version of the flutter project

Comment: what is your flutter version?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue open about this in the packages github repo, take a look at this PR to solve the issue, if it doesnt gets merged ASAP i would recommend you to fork the package, commit the solution and override the package in your pubspec.yaml with the fork you made

https://github.com/brianmtully/flutter_google_ml_vision/pull/37/commits/8ae53444a10e0b6ff8aa2dd90b7fc87e7c68f7d2